# how to make a recursive relationship in sails?

Tags: mongodb, entity-relationship, sails.js, sails-mongo

Diagram:
[image]

I want to have a array with all IDs of the friend users, like this:

```
{
   id: 1
   name: 'Javi',
   email: '123@gmail.com',
   friends: [2]
}

{
    id: 2,
    name: 'User2',
    email: '321@gmail.com',
    friends: [1]
}
```

i tried with this:

```
// User.js <-- model
attributes:{
   name: 'string',
   email:{type:'email', required: true}
   friends:{
     collection: 'User',
     via: 'friends'
   },
}
```

I cannot achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `primaryKey: true` at your id, in that way sails understand your reference.